# Bundle related views into widget and feeding it data

Tags: android

I have a xml file like this

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/book_dialog_btn"
            android:src="@drawable/book"
            android:onClick="showDialog"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/code_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

EditText field must be filled by an integer that is a product id and user can enter that in two ways

- user can either click on imagebutton that opens a dialog containing a list and after user select an item, id will be inserted to edittext
- user know product id and enter it manually

this bits of xml code is repeating in more than one activity so i bundled it into a custom view like this

```
public class PiceBookCodeField extends LinearLayout{

   public PiceBookCodeField (Context context, AttributeSet attr, int defStyle) {
       super(context, attr, defStyle);
       init();
   }

   public PiceBookCodeField (Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
       super(context, attr);
       init();
   }

   public PiceBookCodeField (Context context) {
       super(context);
       init();
   } 

   private void init() {

    LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) inflate(getContext(), R.layout.price_book_code_field, this);

   } 
}
```

and i use below code in xml instead

```
<com.sth.PiceBookCodeField 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

but i dont know how to manage logic related to it.i want to add textwatcher to edittext and when user enter a code search database to check if code exists in database.
but i read somewhere that we must not put data related logic in view but where i should write those logic and avoid duplicating it

Answer (score 0):

add textwatcher and in it start async task.

data search, load, download etc. all must be in async task. make async task to perform search and on it's `onPostExecute` - make changes to your text view according results you got )

Comment: is it a good practice!?i read that we shouldnt start a async task in view for feeding data?

Comment: Will be bad practice when you will fill without async task

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would obtain references to your child views, after which you can configure them further (such as setting `OnClickListener`s or `TextWatcher`s). You can also make public methods on your view which delegate to methods on its children to support the behaviors you want.

```
public class PiceBookCodeField extends LinearLayout {
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private EditText mEditText;

    /* constructors omitted */

    private void init() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.price_book_code_field, this, true);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.book_dialog_btn);
        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.code_field);

        // TODO stuff
    }

    // example method
    public void setCode(String code) {
        mEditText.setText(code);
    }
}
```

One thing that might make sense is to create your own `interface` for various actions your custom view supports. Then in your `init()` method, set whatever listeners you normally would, but have them call your listener interface. Then any user of your view can simply set a listener to take actions when appropriate:

```
public interface CodeFieldListener {
    void onCodeBookClick(PiceBookCodeField view);
    void onCodeEntered(PiceBookCodeField view, String code);
}

private CodeFieldListener mCodeFieldListener;

public void setCodeFieldListener(CodeFieldListener listener) {
    mCodeFieldListener = listener;
}

// inside of init()
mImageView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    if (mCodeFieldListener != null) {
        mCodeFieldListener.onCodeBookClick(this);
    }
});
```

Note that since your custom view is already a LinearLayout, the XML for the children can use the `<merge>` tag as the root instead of `<LinearLayout>`:

```
<merge>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/book_dialog_btn"
        android:src="@drawable/book" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/code_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />
</merge>
```

This way the final hierarchy of your custom view is

```
PiceBookCodeField
    ImageView
    EditText
```

instead of

```
PiceBookCodeField
    LinearLayout
        ImageView
        EditText
```

Comment: Actually i did these stuff in my init method e.g setting text watcher and so on. i just want to know where i should put my sanitizing logic that query database? now i have loader manager that query db but that is repeated in multiple activities and i want to write it in one place and reuse it

Comment: @ramin You could write a default implementation of that interface which does this work, and then anywhere you want this behavior, instantiate one of those.